# Best OCR for formal linguistics papers?

Tags: syntax-trees, logic, software

I have a fair number of formal linguistics papers (generative syntax, semantics) and I am looking for a good OCR software to digitize them as **searchable** PDFs. Unfortunately, the programs I have tried work well for pure text, but choke on IPA, logical symbols and any type of structural tree. Glossed examples with diacritics and indexes also fare poorly.

Can anyone suggest a scan + OCR software for Windows, Linux or Android that works well in the specific domain of linguistics?

Roberto Zamparelli

University of Trento, Italy

Comment: Could you add a list of the software you have tried and found unsuitable for your purpose? Does any of the programs you tried have the option of adding your own custom recognition language by defining its characters set? If the OCR software has such an option, you can add IPA by listing its characters.

Comment: OCR quality also depends on the quality of the original. I've had a lot of trouble but now there are new programs like Nanonets. Have you tried the new programs?